# Apache Cordova missing cordova.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova

I've got a default visual studio 2015 cordova project loaded. I've followed the post from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757057.aspx), but the project won't build.

In my Build output I have the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: EpilepTracker, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.0
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 4.3.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\src\epileptracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker\bld\Android\Release
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\src\epileptracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker\bin\Android\Release
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Release
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Release
1>  ------    projectName: EpilepTracker
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\src\epileptracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In my Javascript Language Service I have the following error:

```
04:13:41.7556: Reference source file successfully generated from references in project 'C:\src\epileptracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker.jsproj'
04:13:41.7796: Reference group 'Implicit (Apache Cordova)' not found.
04:13:41.7876: Referenced file 'C:\src\epileptracker\EpilepTracker\EpilepTracker\www\cordova.js' not found.
04:13:41.7936: Referenced file 'cordova.js' not found.
04:32:14.8630: Reference group 'Implicit (Apache Cordova)' not found.
04:32:14.9430: Referenced file 'cordova.js' not found.
```

From what I've read, visual studio should create the cordova.js file during build, but it doesn't. There are no errors in the Error list. I'm just trying to run a hello world project here.

Comment: Have you installed node and cordova globally? I don't know if Visual Studio do it for you. Because the normal cordova add the cordova.js at build time

Comment: I ran the dependency checker and got: Android SDK The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. I installed SDF, but still no lock

Comment: I love Visual Studio but I would recommend using the Cordova CLI (command line interface) it's easier and you understood which dependencies and commands are using under the hood. Also it isn't so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In config.xml / Platforms select: Use globally installed Cordova version

[image: Imagage Cordova VS]